Publish container image to the JFrog artifactory using Drone Artifactory Plugin
I am using the Drone Artifactory Plugin to publish the artifacts to the Jfrog artifactory.
It helps to push the artifacts and add properties to the artifact, but can I publish the build information with that? and what is the other parameter support for this plugin?
